# Compiler expecting a version of function which "isn't there"

Tags: c++, sdl

I am trying to use [SDL-gfx](http://cms.ferzkopp.net/index.php/software/13-sdl-gfx) with SDL2 on Windows to draw a circle but getting an error message that is difficult (for me) to figure out

I get the error message:

> cannot convert 'SDL_Renderer*' to 'SDL_Surface*' for argument '1' to 'int circleColor(SDL_Surface*, Sint16, Sint16, Sint16, Uint32)*

the only function I see is this one

`SDL2_GFXPRIMITIVES_SCOPE int circleColor(SDL_Renderer * renderer, Sint16 x, Sint16 y, Sint16 rad, Uint32 color);`

but the error message seems to be saying that the function has these parameters

`circleColor(SDL_Surface*, Sint16, Sint16, Sint16, Uint32)`

I cannot find any such function. As far as I know this version of the function doesn't exist on my computer (though obviously I am wrong). How can this be happening?

Thank you

Comment: when I google it, I find `SDL_gfxPrimitives.h` where `circleColor(SDL_Surface *,...` does exist. Maybe you have both?

Comment: You are trying to compile SDL1 code against SDL2 headers. Not going to work as APIs are incompatible.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. SDL2 will work if I comment the function from SDL_gfx. The header file that I am including from SDL_gfx is SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h which is also not from SDL1. Does the error message give you a clue which part of the program is using SDL1?

Answer (score 0):

SDL2-gfx has `SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h` in which you can find this declaration:

> int circleColor(SDL_Renderer * renderer, Sint16 x, Sint16 y, Sint16 rad, Uint32 color);

whereas older SDL-gfx has `SDL_gfxPrimitives.h` which contains:

> int circleColor(SDL_Surface * surface, Sint16 x, Sint16 y,Sint16 r, Uint32 color);

You might have both versions on your computer or you mixed up the headers.